# Conditional Formatting Rows

Tags: excel

So basically I want to change the color of the entire row every time the value in column A (Initiative Number) changes. Ideally I want the colors of the rows to be between dark grey and white.

There doesn't seem to be a specific obvious new conditional formatting rule that fits this. I have tried using the built in conditional formatting rule of uniques and duplicates but that doesn't seem to be helping. Will continue to try things and update here as I do so.

```
Initiative Number (A)   Initiative (B)
I9532                   Initiative I9532: Alberta: Platform Readiness
I8235                   Initiative I8235: Rationalisation of Card Holder      
I8638                   Initiative I8638: EDW - MEA - MTF/ PROD/ DR 
I8638                   Initiative I8638: EDW - MEA - MTF/ PROD/  
I7089                   Initiative I7089: MIP Connectivity for Cloud Customer  
I7089                   Initiative I7089: MIP Connectivity for Cloud Customer  
I7089                   Initiative I7089: MIP Connectivity for Cloud Customer  
I7089                   Initiative I7089: MIP Connectivity for Cloud Customer 
I7089                   Initiative I7089: MIP Connectivity for Cloud Customer
I7089                   Initiative I7089: MIP Connectivity for Cloud Customer 
I1618                   Initiative I1618: UTS - Standardization  
I6018                   Initiative I6018: EDW-MEA-BI-PTS Release and Stage 
I2739                   Initiative I2739: [DPS] Launch ECMS
I2739                   Initiative I2739: [DPS] Launch ECMS
I2739                   Initiative I2739: [DPS] Launch ECMS
```

Comment: Can colors repeat? I.e. can you have white, light grey, medium grey, dark grey, and white again?

Comment: Absolutely. That's actually ideal, just as long as they don't repeat with consecutive unique values in Column A

Comment: Have you tried anything? SO expects user to put in some efforts. Is use of helper column acceptable?

Comment: See above, I have detailed what I have tried

Comment: Is a helper column an option?

Comment: I don't see how a helper column would be useful here as I am not doing any calculations. If someone would be able to slightly elaborate, I'd be happy to give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a helper column and conditional formatting based on a formula to accomplish this.

- In the helper column (column C), add this formula starting in `C2`: `=IF(A2<>A1,IF(C1=4,1,C1+1),C1)`. Change the instances of `4` to however many colors you want to use.
- This will then return `1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4...., 1, 2, 3, 3, 3` representing whether the Initiative Number has changed from the row above, and also what color the row should be - each number represents a different color.
- Assuming you are working with 4 different colors, add 4 new conditional formatting rules based on the formulas `=$C2=1`, `=$C2=2`, `=$C2=3`, and `=$C2=4`, where each rule applies a different fill color.
- Continuing with the example, make sure that the "Applies to" Range is `$A$2:$B$16`.

[image]

You can hide the helper column if needed but included in the screenshot for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, if you do not want to repeat the color formatting with the consecutive unique values in column A (i.e. you simply want to highlight the first occurence of the unique value), you can try the following:

[image]